# change highstock flag to lines on xAxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

hello the following code put flags on series by using type: 'flags' name:'' data:[{}] and so on , "" is there is any way that i can change the flags type to draw lines or areas ?? ""

the code is very simple

```
                  series: [{
                      type: 'line',
                      name: 'AAPL',
                      data: ohlc,
                      id:'dataseries'
                  }, {
                  type: 'flags', 'this is what i wanted to change to lines 
                  name: 'Flags on series',
                  data: [{
                  x: 1114992000000,
                      title: 'On series'
                  }, {
                      x: Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
                      title: 'On series'
           }],
                      onSeries: 'dataseries',
                      shape: 'squarepin'

                  }, {
                      type: 'line',
                      name: 'Volume',
                      data: volume,
                      yAxis: 1

        }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware about [Plot lines](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.plotLines) or [Plot bands](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.plotBands), that highchart supports out of the box?
They haven't given examples of these on x-Axis but they work very much when oriented vertically too

[Vertical Plot lines on x axis @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/RWCua/)